# JDA Events stopped working after updating version

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have a discord bot developed in Java using the latest version of JDA (4.2.0_168).

I have a few events in my bot and only one works.

The `GuildMessageReceivedEvent` works but other events like `GuildMemberJoinEvent`,`GuildMemberRemoveEvent` and `GuildMessageReactionRemoveEvent` don't work.

The problem is before I updated the version everything was working.
I didn't change anything but the `GuildMemberRemoveEvent` in the code so I have no idea what to do. I tried to read the docs but nothing is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that's not the latest version of JDA. It currently is **4.2.0_212** and you can find the latest on [Jenkins](https://ci.dv8tion.net/) any time.

You didn't mention anything about the intents you use so I'll go off on a tangent and assume you don't use intents properly. In order for these events to work you need to enable the `GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS`. This is explained in the *requirements* section of the event [documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/member/GuildMemberJoinEvent.html).

Use `enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)` on your JDABuilder or DefaultShardManagerBuilder. This will allow you to use these events.

I recommend reading the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed) if you experience any other issues.